# Get Data From Json file into Php

Tags: php, getjson, json

hi im trying to get data from json file using php with a url query eg `http://192.168.1.104/testing_JSON/zjson2.php?name=nas`

The following is my code i dont know the syntax to use for retrieving the query.

Thanks in advance

```
$name = ( $_GET['$name'] ); 
$json_string =    file_get_contents("http://192.168.1.104/testing_JSON/newjson.json");
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
$parsed_json = $parsed_json['contacts'];
//pr($parsed_json);

foreach($parsed_json as $key => $value)
{
echo $value['$name'] . '<br>';
echo $value['name'] . '<br>';
// etc
}
?>
```

Comment: can you provide the json string that you get from the url?

Comment: the following is part of newjson.json file {
    "contacts": [
        {
                "id": "c200",
                "name": "Ravi Tamada",
                "email": "ravi@gmail.com",
                "address": "xx-xx-xxxx,x - street, x - country",
                "gender" : "male",
                "phone": {
                    "mobile": "+91 0000000000",
                    "home": "00 000000",
                    "office": "00 000000"
                }
        },

Comment: in your json data phone is also an array. so if you use echo it will cause an error. you need to check array by is_array($value); . if it an array then use another foreach for that $value.

Comment: make `var_dump($parsed_json)` and it'll show a lot of interesting

Comment: please can you suggest some syntax. im new to php .. thanks

Comment: if(is_array($value)){ foreach($value as $var) echo $var;} else echo $value;

Comment: getting the following error Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/testing_JSON/zjson2.php on line 31 (thats the if statement0 line